# Editing pixel data in JavaScript/HTML5 video (Processing to JS translating)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video, processing

I'm attempting to recreate this effect I made for a webcam Processing sketch in JavaScript in order to implement it o n an HTML5 video/canvas tag setup. I'm quite new to all of this and I was just running into some issues to find what functions and such are necessary to perform similar actions (such as pixel reading and adjusting)

Oh and in the web based version I'm building I am using a preloaded video to perform the effect on, not webcam, but that is all set up.

Any help would be super appreciated!!! Thanks!!

```
import processing.video.*;
    Capture video;

    PImage lastImage;
    float threshold = 50;

    float rAdd = random(55);
    float gAdd = random(55);
    float bAdd = random(55);
    float colorAdd;

    void setup() {
      colorMode(HSB);
      size(640, 512);
      smooth();
      video = new Capture(this, width, height, 30);
      video.start();
      lastImage = createImage(video.width, video.height, RGB);
    }

    void draw() {

      lastImage.copy(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
      lastImage.updatePixels();
      video.read();

      loadPixels();
      video.loadPixels();
      lastImage.loadPixels();


      for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
          int loc = x + y*width;
          color current = video.pixels[loc];
          color previous = lastImage.pixels[loc];
          float r1 = red(current);
          float g1 = green(current);
          float b1 = blue(current);
          float r2 = red(previous);
          float g2 = green(previous);
          float b2 = blue(previous);
          float difference = dist(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2);
          if (difference > threshold) {
          //  pixels[loc] += 400;
            colorAdd = random(100,400);
            pixels[loc] = color(r2+rAdd, g2+gAdd, b2+bAdd);
          } 
          else {
           pixels[loc] -= 5;
          }
        }
      }
      updatePixels();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Processing, but I believe the JavaScript mappings are:

**createImage**

[`<canvas>`](http://www.javascripture.com/HTMLCanvasElement) is the HTML drawing surface.  Create one with:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas').
```

From the canvas, you can get a CanvasRenderingContext2D which you use to draw and read from the canvas.  Get it with:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

**lastImage.copy(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);**

You can paint the video to the canvas using the [`context.drawImage()`](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage) method:

```
context.drawImage(video, ...dimensions);
```

**video.pixels**

To get the pixels of the video, use [`context.getImageData()`](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData):

```
var imageData = context.getImageData();

// imageData.data contains the r, g, b, a data from the video
```

**updatePixels()**

Once you have manipulated imageData.data, you can put it back in the canvas with [`context.putImageData()`](http://www.javascripture.com/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData)

```
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```